# Many-to-many self relation with extra fields?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to develop a friends system, and I need a Many-To-Many relation on my User entities ; for now, this is what I've done :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="friends")
 */
protected $friendsWith;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friendsWith")
 * @JoinTable(name="friends",
 *            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *           )
 */
protected $friends;
```

But I would like to have some extra fields for these relations, for example the creation date or the state (accepted, pending, ...) ; I've created another entity "Friend", and I would like this entity to be used as a link between friends. But I don't really know how to manage this...

Do you have some ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm afraid you need an extra class to make such an association.
Here is the tip from doctrine documentation:

> Why are many-to-many associations less common? Because frequently you
>   want to associate additional attributes with an association, in which
>   case you introduce an association class. Consequently, the direct
>   many-to-many association disappears and is replaced by
>   one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating
>   classes.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional

I guess it should be Friend -> Special Association Class (with fileds: user_id, friend_id, date created) ->Friend.
And you associate Friend to special class in two filed $myFriends and $imFriendOf :)

Comment: But I don't really see the associations to make here. :/

User -> OneToMany -> Friend, Friend -> ManyToOne -> User ? There is no 3 classes, but only 2 here 'cause it's a self-association on User

Comment: Ok I think I understand, it's basically the same idea but I just map to another class instead of directly User, isn't it ?

Comment: That's right you have to map to 'association' class because doctrines association doesn't let you to add an extra filed to its 'association db table'.